# Music generation with LSTM - loss stops decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm using a LSTM to generate pieces in the style of Bach. So far, I had success using only the melodic sequences of a single voice, ie, I'm able to generate a single melodic line with a **fixed duration for each note**.

Now, I'm trying to model the **four voices** found on some Bach chorales **and also** the notes duration (see 'Chorales' midis at the bottom of http://www.bachcentral.com/midiindexcomplete.html).

The problem is that, at some point, my LSTM stops learning. Here is my architecture:

For each voice, I extract a sequence of L notes as input, and the next note as output. Then I do the same for the notes duration. So I have:

```
voice0_x = sequence of notes, sequence of duration
voice0_y = next note, next duration

voice1_x = ... the same
voice1_y = ... the same
```

Then the nnet code goes like:

```
input_notes = Input(shape=(notes_in.shape[1], notes_in.shape[2]))
note_out = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(input_notes)

input_durations = Input(shape=(durations_in.shape[1], durations_in.shape[2]))
duration_out = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(input_durations)

merge = concatenate([note_out, duration_out])
merge = Flatten()(merge)
merge = Dense(512, activation='relu')(merge)
merge = Dropout(0.3)(merge)

note_final = Dense(notes_out.shape[1], activation='softmax')(merge)
duration_final = Dense(durations_out.shape[1], activation='softmax')(merge)

model = Model(inputs=[input_notes, input_durations], outputs=[note_final, duration_final])
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer = 'rmsprop')
```

So, I just feed the notes and durations sequences to separate LSTM's, concatenate their outputs and send everything to a dense layer. The network is clearly learning, but the loss stops decreasing at ~12.35:

```
loss: 12.3549 - dense_2_loss: 6.3240 dense_3_loss: 6.0309
```

I tried increasing the number of LSTM cells, without success. Given that the melodic lines of each voice have a relation with each other (the same goes for durations), is that the correct architecture? Should I increase even more the number of cells?

To be a little bit more clear, suppose that my goal is to 'overfit' the input data, so in theory the network should converge to a small loss value, but that's not happening.

Thanks for your help, and I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Have you tried using sklearn grid search with the different hyper parameters of LSTM? It may give you some clue.

Comment: That's not an option, it takes too much processing time.

Comment: If the network seems to learning but gets stuck in a minima, then you can try using the clipnorm or clipvalue options provided with the [optimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/). Another thing that you could try is to use a [BatchNorm](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) layer and enabling dropout options with the LSTM

Comment: @kvish Ok, I'll look into that, thanks!